# In a completely javascript web app how do you make it so that you can click the backspace and go to the previous action?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a javascript web app that I am trying to make so you can use the back button on the browser with. How do you do this? I have seen it done but can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most javascript frameworks support these things. This one is from jquery: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/history. If it is a "completely javascript" app, you would be having some framework there. If not, jquery would be the fastest to plug in. YUI also supports history

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need it to be cross-browser (e.g. in a personal project), you can use the relatively recent [onhashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) event. More interesting than using a library :) If you want to be even more cutting edge, try [History.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). Cross-browser solutions can be found in many frameworks, including [some standalone ones](http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/).

Comment: onhashchange is supported in IE8+, Opera 10.something, Safari, Firefox, and Chrome.

Comment: Yup. Basically the most recent crop :)

Answer (score 1):

You can access the browser history using history.

add an onclick to a button or however suits you:

```
onclick="history.go(-1);return false;"
```

Comment: you could also trap the `keydown` event, check the `keycode` to see if it's a backspace, and then act accordingly.